# Non analytic sets?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I'm studying Jech's *Set Theory* and I noticed that he doesn't show an example of a non analytic set. Of course the analytic sets are Lebesgue measurable, have the Baire property and the perfect set property, so I know a few obvious examples.

Can you show me a *less ugly* subset of $\mathbb R$ that is not the projection of a closed set in $\mathbb R^2$?
(I know the definition was with a Borel set in $X\times\mathcal N$ but $\mathbb R^2$ is easier to work with, so...)

My guess is that $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ may not be analytic but I have no proof for it.

Comment: The simplest examples will be among the co-analytic sets (complements of analytic sets). Google together the phrase "co-analytic set" and the word "examples".

Comment: Well, $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ is the difference between two Borel sets, so it's a Borel set as well. Definitely analytic.

Comment: To expand on @DaveL.Renfro's comment, it is a theorem that if $A$ and $A^c$ are both analytic, then $A$ is Borel.  So if you choose a set $A$ which is analytic but not Borel, then $A^c$ is not analytic.

Comment: See also [HERE](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/measure) and the google-hits for Howard Becker's 1992 paper [*Descriptive set theoretic phenomena in analysis and topology*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Descriptive+set+theoretic+phenomena+in+analysis+and+topology%22).

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you can find good examples of non-analytic sets in Kechris book $\textit{Classical Descriptive Set Theory}$. For example the set $WO$ of codes of countable ordinals is $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_1$-complete. Also, say a linear order $(A,<)$ is scaterred if there is no order preserving map from of $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ into $(A,<)$. Then let $x \in SCAT \leftrightarrow x$ codes a linear order and $A_x$ is scattered. Then $SCAT$ is $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_1$-complete. A last nice example (still in Kechris and due to Marzurkiewickz) is that the set of all differentiable function in $C([0,1])$ is $\boldsymbol\Pi^1_1$-complete (and so is the set of continuous functions with everywhere convergent Fourier series, Atjai-Kechris). I am sure there are plenty of examples in the higher pointclasses as there is a whole industry devoted to this nice subject of finding sets of objects and computing their exact complexity.